# What would be the gate design for a 2 bit multiplier for signed binary?

Tags: logic

I understand how a normal 2 bit multiplier works but it only works for positive numbers, so how would it work with signed binary.

i tried using nand gates, half adders, and a xor gate

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference between signed/unsigned multiplication operations. It'll work correctly, both for signed and unsigned inputs; so long as you interpret your input/output correctly.

For instance, consider the multiplication of 2-bit numbers `10` * `11`. If you designed your circuit correctly, it should output `10`.

- If interpreted unsigned; this'll be 2 *  3 = 2
- If interpreted signed, this'll be  -2 * -1 = 2

So in either case, you get the same bit-pattern. In fact, one of the reasons why we use 2's complement representation of integers is precisely because addition/subtraction/multiplication remains exactly the same both for signed and unsigned variants. (But this isn't true for division, and comparison operators; for which you have to have custom designs for signed/unsigned versions.)